# How to write the following vector

Tags: math-mode, matrices, vector

I have written a vector

```
\begin{align}
   \textbf{\underline w} &= \begin{bmatrix}
          \textbf{0} \\
          \textbf{v} \\
          \textbf{0}
          \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
```

However I want to write the number of elements in the vector too.
That is I want to write it like `0_{1\times 4}` then `v_{1\times 5}` and so on.

Is it possible to write that in the vector `w` ?

How to do it?

Please help.

Comment: what is the problem? please clarify!

Comment: Although this is a personnal opition, I would not use such notations. Why would `w` be underlined and not  `v` ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `\mathbf`, not `\textbf`.

```
\begin{equation}
\underline{\mathbf{w}}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{0}_{1\times 4}\\
\mathbf{v}_{1\times 5}\\
\mathbf{0}_{1\times 4}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

Probably the figures should be switched, though.